# Describing a design pattern of cloning an record instance

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement an application but didn't want to reinvent the wheel. I've been searching for an design pattern closest to this application but to no avail.

1. On startup, the application will prompt the administrator to choose from a list of tasks and copy the selected task into this year's tasks.
2. Throughout the year, a normal user will be able to check off the completed tasks.
3. At the end of the year, the administrator will indicate the year's tasks as closed. This means the tasks cannot be deleted, amended and no new tasks can be added.
4. The administrator will copy the completed year's tasks into the next year's tasks.

Does any one know if a design pattern or sample code (or pseudo-code) available that matches this?

Comment: This is just ordinary programming.  You write code that performs these actions.  Copying records in any database system is a routine operation, and I'm assuming that you're going to use a database if this is a non-trivial application.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Robert Harvey. Yes I'll be using a database. I'll think it through and start with pseudo-code

Comment: I would suggest spending some time making sure the schema you use in your database is a good fit for your requirements, otherwise you might end up with some messy queries.    Here's a similar/related question on DBA.SE about how to structure *'historical'* data in a SQL database without creating duplicated rows in the main table:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35627/best-practices-for-history-temporal-tables

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do not need to "move" lists at all. You just need to attribute the tasks.

You could have a single table and/or entity that contains/aggregates all tasks regardless of status or "year."  Let's step through the workflow given this design:

**On startup**

> On startup, the application will prompt the administrator to choose from a list of tasks and copy the selected task into this year's tasks.

The system retrieves a list of all tasks that are in an "unassigned" state and displays them to the administrator. The administrator checks off some of the tasks, and the system changes the status to "assigned."

Any remaining unassigned tasks could be left as is (meaning the administrator would be prompted with them the next time he accesses the system) or they could be moved to a "deferred" status.

**Normal users check off tasks**

> Throughout the year, a normal user will be able to check off the completed tasks.

The system retrieves and displays all tasks with a status of "assigned." User can check them off.  As he does so, the system changes the status to "completed."

**Year end closure**

> At the end of the year, the administrator will indicate the year's tasks as closed. This means the tasks cannot be deleted, amended and no new tasks can be added.

The system retrieves all tasks with a status of "completed." After administrator approval, the status of these tasks is changed to "closed."

The system allows only read-only access to tasks that are marked closed.

**Moving tasks to the next year**

> The administrator will copy the completed year's tasks into the next year's tasks.

Any tasks remaining in an "assigned" status are carried forward.

Notice that this design lacks any notion of "year." Seems to me that there is always only one year active at any time, so it isn't really needed; you just need to know which tasks are assigned or completed.  If you need them to have a "year" assigned to them, e.g. for reports or metrics, you could store a `DateAssigned`, `DateCompleted`, and `DateClosed` for each task and run reports by year, or by other time period if your organization ever moves to quarters or fiscal years or whathaveyou.

If "year" really is a mission-critical concept in your data model, you can of course add another column for "year." The act of "moving" tasks from one year to another simply means updating that column. You don't have to move anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may be asking yourself the wrong question, at this point in time, it may seem as simple as copying the record, but in the future, and even now, it is not. You will at the very least, have to toggle the completed property. You will also have to check for access to see if the user has permission to do so.

Execution:

```
var task = repository.GetTask(id);
if (!currentUser.CanTransfer(task))
{
    throw new ApplicationException(" Sorry, I can't let you do that :( ");
}
var newTask = task.TransferToNextYear();
repository.Save(newTask);
```

Class Def:

```
public class Task : ITransferable
{
   string Key;
   DateTime? CompletedDate;
   DateTime CreateDate;
   string AssignedUser;
   // Lots of other fields

   public Task TransferToNextYear()
   {
       var newTask = new Task();
       newTask.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
       newTask.CompletedDate = null;
       newTask.AssignedUser = null;
       newTask.string Key = GetNewKey();
       //Copy other fields
       return newTask;
   }
}
```